# How to make leap motion not detect swipe gesture

Tags: leap-motion

I want to detect swipe gesture direction only "up/down" and "right/left".
When I stretch my hands to forward, leap motion should not detect that motion to swipe gesture.
How could I make it?

```
    String swipeDirection;

    GestureList gestures = frame.gestures();
    for(int i=0; i<gestures.count(); i++){
        Gesture gesture = gestures.get(i);

        if(gesture.type()==gesture.type().TYPE_SWIPE){
            SwipeGesture swipeGesture = new SwipeGesture(gesture);
            boolean isHorizontal = Math.abs(swipeGesture.direction().get(0))>Math.abs(swipeGesture.direction().get(1));
            if(isHorizontal){
                if(swipeGesture.direction().get(0)>0){
                    swipeDirection = "right";
                }else{
                    swipeDirection="left";
                }
            }else{
                if(swipeGesture.direction().get(1)>0){
                    swipeDirection="up";
                }else{
                    swipeDirection = "down";
                }
            }
            System.out.println("direction: "+swipeDirection + " hand: "+frame.hands().get(0).isLeft()
                    +", duration: "+swipeGesture.durationSeconds());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that the direction is pointing more towards the x or y axes than toward the z axis. So similar to how you calculate whether the swipe direction is horizontal, you want to check that it isn't forward/backward:

```
boolean isNotForward = Math.abs(swipeGesture.direction().get(0)) >
                       Math.abs(swipeGesture.direction().get(2)) || 
                       Math.abs(swipeGesture.direction().get(1)) >
                       Math.abs(swipeGesture.direction().get(2));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But It still detect forward/backward gesture. I want to detect more precisely. I add your code like this

if(isHorizontal&&isNotForward){
...
}else if(!isHorizontal&&isNotForward){
...
}

Did i make wrong code?

Comment: Comparing the components of the direction vector this way is somewhat crude -- it will only tell you that the direction is more along one axis than the other -- so something around 45 degrees forward could still be considered horizontal or vertical. If you want to restrict it to a lesser angle than that, then you can compare the direction vector to axis directly (i.e. with the AngleTo() function or dot product).